# Can you explain the distributed Tensorflow tutorial example?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm somewhat new to the world of distributed computing. I was reading the [following](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)  from the official tensorflow tutorial, but I got quite confused about what is going on in the main example of the tutorial.

In particular, how do the ps jobs and workers interact? What exactly is the role of ps jobs? Their corresponding part in the code is quite limited and they seem not to be doing much, so what is their purpose? I guess I don't understand how various parts of our distributed system work together.

It would be great if someone could explain what happens exactly as you execute the shell commands at the end in terms of different processes and their actions.

Here is the main code for reference:

```python
import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None

def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      # Build model...
      loss = ...
      global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step)

    # The StopAtStepHook handles stopping after running given steps.
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000000)]

    # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
    # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
    # or an error occurs.
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                           checkpoint_dir="/tmp/train_logs",
                                           hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
      while not mon_sess.should_stop():
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.
        # mon_sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.
        mon_sess.run(train_op)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
  # Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
  parser.add_argument(
      "--ps_hosts",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--worker_hosts",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--job_name",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="One of 'ps', 'worker'"
  )
  # Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
  parser.add_argument(
      "--task_index",
      type=int,
      default=0,
      help="Index of task within the job"
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Here is the shell commands:

```bash
  $ python trainer.py\
  --ps_hosts = ps0.example.com: 2222, ps1.example.com: 2222\
  --worker_hosts = worker0.example.com: 2222, worker1.example.com: 2222\
  --job_name = ps--task_index = 0# On ps1.example.com:
  $ python trainer.py\
  --ps_hosts = ps0.example.com: 2222, ps1.example.com: 2222\
  --worker_hosts = worker0.example.com: 2222, worker1.example.com: 2222\
  --job_name = ps--task_index = 1# On worker0.example.com:
  $ python trainer.py\
  --ps_hosts = ps0.example.com: 2222, ps1.example.com: 2222\
  --worker_hosts = worker0.example.com: 2222, worker1.example.com: 2222\
  --job_name = worker--task_index = 0# On worker1.example.com:
  $ python trainer.py\
  --ps_hosts = ps0.example.com: 2222, ps1.example.com: 2222\
  --worker_hosts = worker0.example.com: 2222, worker1.example.com: 2222\
  --job_name = worker--task_index = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a schematic diagram of the situation. You have 4 tensorflow processes. Each process runs TensorFlow worker thread which can execute TensorFlow computations. Additionally, two of the processes are also running a client thread which issues `session.run` requests.

[image]

Each worker process is also a "device" in TensorFlow for the purpose of splitting graph execution over devices. You can tell TF runtime to execute some part of graph on worker1 device by doing something like `with tf.device("job:worker/task:0"):` during graph construction.

There's magic happening in `tf.train.replica_device_setter` which takes place of the manual `with tf.device` annotations and has the effect of automatically assigning variables across devices. More specifically, when you have two PS shards, half of the variables will go onto ps1 device and another half on ps2 device. Meanwhile the part of the graph that updates those variables will be replicated on each worker device.

If you replaced `replica_device_setter` with manual device specifications, your worker process would roughly look like this

```
with tf.device('ps1'):
  var1 = tf.Variable(...)
with tf.device('ps2'):
  var2 = tf.Variable(...)
with tf.device('worker1'):
  update_op1 = var1.assign_add(grad1)
  update_op2 = var2.assign_add(grad2)

while True:
  sess.run([update_op1, update_op2])
```

Communication is automatically taken care of. When you execute `sess.run(update_op1)` in worker1 client thread, it will compute `grad1` on worker1, then send the result to ps1 task, and trigger ps1 worker thread to update its value of `var1`

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, the ps job contains all the shared data between different tasks, which can run on different machines (and all share the same ps job).

Comment: That makes sense expect for the fact that there are two ps tasks in the code. Why should there be two? What would happen for instance if we ran the same code but eliminated one of the ps tasks. 

If the ps tasks are there just for synchronization, I don't see why we need two.